# Passing variables to XSD File which turns it into XML file

Tags: xml, variables, input, xsd

I have a XML scheme in which i have 4 different dimensions. The later created XML Tags however arent the same and have to be created with userinput or something. The xml tag names should be variables in the xml scheme. I am wondering if it is possible, that i can pass these variables to the xml scheme so i can later automatically create individual xml files with individual xml tags.
Im a beginner programmer with a little bit of experience in y

Sorry for my bad english or if it is hard to understand english is not my mothertongue. I hope, that what i wrote is understandable.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name = "xml-tag1" maxOccurs = "unbounded" minOccurs = "0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "xml-tag2" maxOccurs = "unbounded" minOccurs = "0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name = "xml-tag3" maxOccurs = "unbounded" minOccurs = "0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name = "xml-tag4" maxOccurs = "unbounded" minOccurs = "0">
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>

xml-tag1 = input
xml-tag2 = input
xml-tag3 = input
xml-tag4 = input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD doesn't support this directly. You could parameterise the schema by using entity references for the element names, or you could generate the schema dynamically using XSLT.

However, if I were advising you professionally, I would be asking some searching questions about whether you are going down the right road. What you're attempting is pretty weird, and I would want to see a strong rationale for not using a more conventional solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What would be a more conventional solution?

Comment: @notDaniel: You've only posted a (unconventional) method for achieving some unspecified higher level goal.  Teasing out your actual goal would take some time, but note this:  XSDs are primarily for validating XML documents.  Generating XML document instances from a schema is an underspecified problem since many XML documents instances could be valid against a given XSD.

Comment: @notDaniel Echoing kjhughes, I can't offer a solution without knowing the problem. You haven't said WHY you are doing this.

Comment: @MichaelKay I havee a programm that generates big CSV files. They need to be turned into xml files so i can upload them to a website. The problem with thes CSV files is, that they have different headers and different structures but have to be converted in a specific XML format. I thought i could use a XSD file as a formatting scheme. But that does  not seem to work does it? Did my explanation help you?

Comment: I can't see any reason for using XSD in this workflow. It sounds like a straightforward XSLT task.